# How to display and save all images in current working directory

Tags: python-3.x, opencv, image-processing

I am trying to denoise the images in current working directory. I can successfully read all the images from dir and I am able to apply a median Blur on those images. Now I want to display and save these new processed images in new image files. Here is error i am getting

> cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\highgui\src\window.cpp:352: error: (-215:Assertion failed) size.width>0 && size.height>0 in function 'cv::imshow'

```
import cv2
import numpy as np
import os
from PIL import Image
for image in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    img = cv2.imread(image)
    blur_image = cv2.medianBlur(img,5)
    print("sucess")

for i,image in enumerate(image):
    cv2.imshow("Image number {}".format(i), img)
```

How can I save and display these new images?

Comment: Why write any Python to do this? Just use **ImageMagick** in Terminal to apply a 5x5 median filter to all PNG files... `magick mogrify -median 5x5 *.png`

Comment: You are love buddy thanks for this tip. As I just need to pre-process the images so I don't care whether to use python or this ImagicMagic <3

Comment: but i was more intrested to use python as i am working on ML project where i need to apply different preprocessing techniques which i need to search in ImageMagic before proceeding

Answer (score 0):

just add `cv2.imwrite('path', img)` and this should work just fine.

Comment: ERROR !!! cv2.error: OpenCV(4.1.1) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgcodecs\src\loadsave.cpp:662: error: (-2:Unspecified error) could not find a writer for the specified extension in function 'cv::imwrite_'

Comment: Okay I got what issue you are facing. Apparently, `os.listdir(os.getcwd())` this returns all the files in the working directory, which probably contain not only image files but also some other file types, which is causing the error. Apparently, `cv2` doesn't throw any error for non-image file, but it cannot display them.

Comment: Moreover, as you mentioned the error in the comments `could not find a writer for the specified extension in function`, this specifically says that it couldn't find a writer for the specified *extension*

Comment: but i have to run the code for the images in the current dir so the python file should be in the same dir, if i do so the error will always occur. How can i avoid it?

Comment: and I have images in JPG extension. and as per my knowledge OpenCV should work with JPG if I am not wrong.

Comment: What you can do is instead of searching in current directory, create a folder in the direction and pass the relative path to the folder in the loop, and extract the file. In that way, you can make sure that only the jpg files are getting extracted.

Comment: glad I could be of help :)

Comment: If my solution worked for you, you might as well consider accepting my answer so that in future if anyone stumbles upon the same then they can get help easily.